# Troubles storing and loading custom object into NSUserDefaults Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I've been trying to store and recover from the `NSUserDefaults` an Array of custom objects in my project but it seems something is going wrong. I've researched a lot about this issue but I couldn't find any answer to my problem.

It seems that the storing it's done OK because I don't get any error when saving data in `NSUserDefaults`, the problem comes when I try to get back those data: the app will crash completely with `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` error.

Here's my code:

`Wine.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import UIKit;

#define NO_RATING -1

      @interface WineModel  : NSObject <NSCoding>
        @property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *type; 
        @property(strong, nonatomic) UIImage *photo;
        @property(strong, nonatomic) NSURL *photoURL;
        @property(strong, nonatomic) NSURL *wineCompanyWeb;
        @property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *notes;
        @property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *origin;
        @property(nonatomic) int rating;
        @property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *grapes;
        @property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
        @property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *wineCompanyName;

        - (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder;
        - (void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) encoder;

//SOME OTHER METHODS...//

-(id) initWithName: (NSString *) aName
   wineCompanyName: (NSString *) aWineCompanyName
              type: (NSString *) aType
            origin: (NSString *) anOrigin
            grapes: (NSArray *) arrayOfGrapes
    wineCompanyWeb: (NSURL *) aURL
             notes: (NSString *) aNotes
            rating: (int) aRating
          photoURL: (NSURL *) aPhotoURL;

//For JSON
-(id) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *) aDict;

@end
```

`Wine.m`

```
    #import "WineModel.h"
@implementation WineModel

@synthesize photo = _photo;

#pragma mark - Properties
-(UIImage *) photo {
    //SOME MORE CODE...
    return _photo;

}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        self.wineCompanyName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"company"];
        self.type = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"type"];
        self.origin = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"origin"];
        self.grapes = [self extractGrapesFromJSONArray:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"grapes"]];
        self.wineCompanyWeb = [NSURL URLWithString:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"wine_web"]];
        self.notes = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"notes"];
        self.rating = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"rating"] intValue];
        self.photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"picture"]];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.wineCompanyWeb forKey:@"company"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.type forKey:@"type"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.origin forKey:@"origin"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.grapes forKey:@"grapes"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.wineCompanyWeb forKey:@"wine_web"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.notes forKey:@"notes"];
    [encoder encodeInt:self.rating forKey:@"rating"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.photoURL forKey:@"picture"];
}

#pragma mark - Init

-(id) initWithName: (NSString *) aName
   wineCompanyName: (NSString *) aWineCompanyName
              type: (NSString *) aType
            origin: (NSString *) anOrigin
            grapes: (NSArray *) arrayOfGrapes
    wineCompanyWeb: (NSURL *) aURL
             notes: (NSString *) aNotes
            rating: (int) aRating
          photoURL: (NSURL *) aPhotoURL {

    if(self==[super init]) {
        _name = aName;
        _wineCompanyName = aWineCompanyName;
        _type = aType;
        _origin = anOrigin;
        _grapes = arrayOfGrapes;
        _wineCompanyWeb = aURL;
        _notes = aNotes;
        _rating = aRating;
        _photoURL = aPhotoURL;
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - JSON

-(id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDict {
    return [self initWithName:[aDict objectForKey:@"name"]
              wineCompanyName:[aDict objectForKey:@"company"]
                         type:[aDict objectForKey:@"type"]
                       origin:[aDict objectForKey:@"origin"]
                       grapes:[self extractGrapesFromJSONArray:[aDict objectForKey:@"grapes"]]
                wineCompanyWeb:[NSURL URLWithString:[aDict objectForKey:@"wine_web"]]
                        notes:[aDict objectForKey:@"notes"]
                       rating:[[aDict objectForKey:@"rating"]intValue]
                     photoURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[aDict objectForKey:@"picture"]]
            ];
}

-(NSArray *) extractGrapesFromJSONArray: (NSArray *)JSONArray {

    //SOME MORE CODE...

    return grapes;
}

@end
```

This is the wine class. It has the `<NSCoding>` protocol and both methods  `(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder;` and `(void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder *) encoder;`. So far I looks OK, lets move on to the next class:

`Winery.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Wine.h"

#define RED_WINE_KEY @"Red"
#define WHITE_WINE_KEY @"White"
#define OTHER_WINE_KEY @"Others"

@interface WineryModel : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *redWines;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *whiteWines;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *otherWines;

@property(readonly, nonatomic) int redWineCount;
@property(readonly, nonatomic) int whiteWineCount;
@property(readonly, nonatomic) int otherWineCount;


-(WineModel *) redWineAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index; 
-(WineModel *) whiteWineAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;
-(WineModel *) otherWineAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;

@end
```

`Winery.m`

```
#import "Winery.h"
@implementation WineryModel

#pragma mark - Properties

-(int) redWineCount { 
    return [self.redWines count];
}

-(int) whiteWineCount {
    return [self.whiteWines count];
}

-(int) otherWineCount {
    return [self.otherWines count];
}

-(id) init {
    if(self == [super init]) {

        NSUserDefaults *userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//Check if there is data stored locally 
        if(([[[userDefault dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"redWines"])
           &&([[[userDefault dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"whiteWines"])
           &&([[[userDefault dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"otherWines"])) {

            if([userDefault objectForKey:@"redWines"] != nil && [userDefault objectForKey:@"whiteWines"] != nil && [userDefault objectForKey:@"otherWines"] != nil) {
                //Try to load data from NSUserDefaults
                NSData *decodedRedWines = [userDefault objectForKey:@"redWines"];
                self.redWines = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedRedWines] mutableCopy]; //IT WILL CRASH HERE
                NSData *decodedWhiteWines = [userDefault objectForKey:@"whiteWines"];
                self.whiteWines = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedWhiteWines] mutableCopy];
                NSData *decodedOtherWines = [userDefault objectForKey:@"otherWines"];
                self.otherWines = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedOtherWines] mutableCopy];

            }

        } else {

            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/wines.json"]]; //JSON URL

            NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
            NSError *error;
            NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                             error:&error];
            if(data != nil) { //No errors

                //Passing from JSON to an NSArray
                NSArray * JSONObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                        options:kNilOptions
                                                                          error:&error];
                if (JSONObjects != nil) {
                    //No errors
                    for(NSDictionary *dict in JSONObjects){

                        WineModel *wine = [[WineModel alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
                        if(wine.name != nil && wine.wineCompanyName != nil && wine.type != nil && wine.origin != nil ) {
                            if ([wine.type isEqualToString:RED_WINE_KEY]) {
                                if (!self.redWines) {
                                    self.redWines = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:wine];
                                }
                                else {
                                    [self.redWines addObject:wine];
                                }
                            }
                            else if ([wine.type isEqualToString:WHITE_WINE_KEY]) {
                                if (!self.whiteWines) {
                                    self.whiteWines = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:wine];
                                }
                                else {
                                    [self.whiteWines addObject:wine];
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                if (!self.otherWines) {
                                    self.otherWines = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:wine];
                                }
                                else {
                                    [self.otherWines addObject:wine];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"JSON parsing error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Server error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
            //Storing the array of wine objects in the NSUserDefaults
            NSData *encodedRedWines = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_redWines];
            [userDefault setObject:encodedRedWines forKey:@"redWines"];
            NSData *encodedWhiteWines = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_whiteWines];
            [userDefault setObject:encodedWhiteWines forKey:@"whiteWines"];
            NSData *encodedOtherWines = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_otherWines];
            [userDefault setObject:encodedOtherWines forKey:@"otherWines"];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(WineModel *) redWineAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index {
    return [self.redWines objectAtIndex:index];
}


-(WineModel *) whiteWineAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index{
    return [self.whiteWines objectAtIndex:index];
}


-(WineModel *) otherWineAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index{
    return [self.otherWines objectAtIndex:index];
}

@end
```

So, the first time you launch the app it will download the data from a JSON file that is in the web, then store the info in the NSUserDefaults. It seems like this step it's done correctly (at least doesn't crash at this point). The problem comes after launching the app the second time. It will check if there are local data store under the NSUserDefault, if so, it'll try to load the data and store into an NSMutableAtray. Unfortunately it won't do so, It crashes here `self.redWines =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedRedWines];` with the error code I wrote before. When debugging, I can see that there is data when retrieving the `redWines`key, but it seems like something it's going wrong.

Mind that I'm using a customized initializer (`initWithDictionary`) for creating my wines object instead of the default `init` method. I don't know if it could be the reason of the crash...

Here's the full log:

```
2017-05-22 20:31:30.354640+0200 App[1905:891526] -[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5c064950b08843b
2017-05-22 20:31:30.354932+0200 App[1905:891526] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5c064950b08843b'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18e0bafe0 0x18cb1c538 0x18e0c1ef4 0x18e0bef54 0x18dfbad4c 0x1000591d8 0x100057dec 0x18eb0a430 0x18eb10f10 0x18eaa684c 0x18eb0a430 0x18eb09b68 0x18eb08d94 0x100061118 0x1000621d0 0x10005c120 0x19425d204 0x194469738 0x19446f1e0 0x194483d18 0x19446c474 0x18fc63884 0x18fc636f0 0x18fc63aa0 0x18e06942c 0x18e068d9c 0x18e0669a8 0x18df96da4 0x194256384 0x194251058 0x100060b90 0x18cfa559c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` in libobjc.A.dylib or `[NSException raise]` in CoreFoundation?  I suspect you'll find the problem pretty quickly if you can trace it back to the exact element that it's choking on.

Comment: Can you log `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedRedWines]` this line and tell me the type of the returned object?

Like this: `NSLog(@"%@", [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedRedWines]);` This will help to know what exactly you have stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Hi Hemang, thanks for your comment. I tried your suggestion but I didn't get an output in NSLog, instead I got this error: [NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5c064950b08843b
App[3437:1872740] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5c064950b08843b'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18e0bafe0 0x18cb1c538 0x18e0c1ef4…0x194251058 0x1000c4acc 0x18cfa559c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your initWithCoder method:

self.wineCompanyName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"**comapny**"];

If that does not fix it, I would look at the NSUserDefaults documentation more closely - it says "Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value."  Your redWines property is  defined as an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed the typo (I hate this stupid mistakes) and I also tried adding three new non mutable NSArrays to check if that was the problem but I still get the same results... I'll update the thread in order to show you is it now.

Answer (score 0):

To make an immutable object mutable just call `mutableCopy`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *redWines;

...

self.redWines = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedRedWines] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I'll try that too, but I'm not sure if the problem was that I was using non mutable arrays instead of mutable ones.

Comment: Your code with both types looks confusing. If you really need mutable objects delete the immutable ones. And it would be helpful to add the actual reason of the exception.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, both types makes it a bit confusing. I'll update the thread again so you can see the changes, but I'm still getting the same crash :(

Comment: Add breakpoints and debug the code or print the output of the unarchived object.

Comment: I added these break points: 1. if(([[[userDefault dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"redWines"])
           &&(...)) 

2. NSData *decodedRedWines = [userDefault objectForKey:@"redWines"];

3. self.redWines = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedRedWines] mutableCopy];

4. NSData *encodedRedWines = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_redWines];

5. [userDefault setObject:encodedRedWines forKey:@"redWines"];

Comment: The first time I launch the App it will stop in the first breakpoint. The condition is not fulfilled so it downloads everything from the web. Then it’ll stop in the fourth and fifth breakpoint. After that the app runs properly.

The problem comes when I launch the app again. It’ll stop in the first breakpoint, now the condition is fulfilled so it’ll go through the code inside the if. It stops in the second breakpoint (no errors yet), but when it reaches the third one it will crash after stepping over, with libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.
Any ideas?

Comment: Once again, **what** exception? And update synchronous deprecated `NSURLConnection` to `URLSession`

Comment: I had to change the environment variable OS_ACTIVITY_MODE since Xcode wasn't showing me the full exception: App[1882:874114] -[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5c064950b08843b
2017-05-22 19:48:53.913814+0200 App[1882:874114] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa5c064950b08843b'

Comment: The error is not related to mutable / immutable. The object you send `objectForKey` to is a string rather than expected dictionary. Check how the data is stored.

Comment: The data is supposed to be stored by using  NSData *encodedRedWines = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_redWines];
            [userDefault setObject:encodedRedWines forKey:@"redWines"]; So what I'm trying to do is store an NSArray into the NSUserDefaults after encoding it with its key... Might be something going wrong with the storage? I can't find out what :/